# Simple Linear Regression with constraint using Math.net and C#

Tags: c#, linear-regression, mathnet-numerics

I'm using  Math.net and C# for simple linear regression of two double arrays (XValues, YValues) which contain physiological data. There are good grounds for constraining the intercept to the origin.
At the moment I'm using:

```
Tuple<double, double> r = Fit.Line(XValues, YValues);
double YIntercept = r.Item1;
double Slope = r.Item2; ...etc.
```

Can anyone provide the code snippet to force the regression line to pass through zero. - I am not able to understand the answer provided in the only relevant question on StackOverflow

Comment: Could you provide a link to that other question?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use `Fit.LineThroughOrigin`, which forces the intercept to be 0

```
Tuple<double, double> r = Fit.LineThroughOrigin(XValues, YValues);
```

If what you want is the function itself, use `LineThroughOriginFunc`.